# LayoutManager - Null pointer exception when setting RecyclerView to ListVIew header

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal RecyclerView which I'm adding as a header of a Listview. But as soon as I open my activity, it crashes.

This is what I'm doing in my activity:

```
headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(headerView, this);
holder.inflateView();
listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

And inside my view holder constructor:

```
    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView, Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        mainView = itemView;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
```

And inside my view holder inflate method :

```
adapter = new CustomHorizontalAdapter(mActivity, list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my view XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But as soon as I open my activity, it crashes with the following logs -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1944)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1867)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:581)
```

Can somebody help me understand why this is crashing? I set the layout manager to the recycler view. Is there any other way to add a horizontal scrolling view as a header to a listview? Is it not possible?

Comment: Is your `CustomViewHolder` part of `RecyclerViewAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with Recyclerview's layout manager.

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Your custom view holder should return only holder, please move setting up layout and setting up adapter in activity's onCreateView.